# YouTrack sort by multiple fields

Tags: sorting, youtrack

I use YouTrack online by Jetbrains for issue tracking, but have found that it appears to not support sorting by multiple fields. For example, if I enter this search phrase: `order by: Priority asc, created desc` then it will only sort by the Priority of the issue ascending.

Within each priority, the dates are not sorted (I want the most recently filed ones at the top of each priority grouping).

Also, if I change the search to: `order by: created desc` then it sorts the entire list by created date descending, but of course lose the priority groupings.

My conclusion is that it is only supporting a single level sort - Anyone know if there is a way to achieve the functionality I desire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTrack does support sorting by multiple fields, here's an example: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=order+by%3A+Priority+asc%2C+created+desc .
So I suggest that you contact YouTrack support on this issue.

Comment: Looks like on the GUI, YouTrack shows the date from the "last action" in the list view there on the top level and not "created date" so it was confusing and looked like it wasn't sorting properly when it actually was. Thanks for the clarification that it does indeed work!